# Why cannot I resolve keyed registrations from lifetime scope?

Tags: dependency-injection, scope, autofac

I'm trying to resolve keyed service from a lifetime scope. The following code presents the issue:

```cs
public class Service1 : IService1 { }

public interface IService1 { }

public class Service2 : IService2 
{
    public Service2([KeyFilter("Test")] IService1 service1) { }
}

public class IService2 { }

public static class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterType<Service1>().Named<IService1>("Test");
        builder.RegisterType<Service2>().As<IService2>();
        var container = builder.Build();

        using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
        {
            var service2 = scope.Resolve<IService2>();
        }
    }
}
```

My intention is to create multiple `Service1`s registrations per specific other services. I need scopes, because I have registered DbContext as scoped and services needs it to work properly.

After starting the demo code, I'm getting the exception:

```
Autofac.Core.DepencencyResolutionException: 'An exception was thrown while activating ManagedConsoleSketchbook.Service2.'

Inner Exception
DependencyResolutionException: None of the constructors found on type 'ManagedConsoleSketchbook.Service2' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
Cannot resolve parameter 'ManagedConsoleSketchbook.IService1 service1' of constructor 'Void .ctor(ManagedConsoleSketchbook.IService1)'.
```

Am I doing something wrong? Why cannot I resolve named/keyed service from a lifetime scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[If you read the docs on the `KeyFilterAttribute`](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/metadata.html#keyfilterattribute) you'll notice you forgot to add `.WithAttributeFiltering()` to the `Service2` registration. Attribute filtering is a perf hit so it's opt-in.